# Rational class writing add and multiply methods

Tags: java, biginteger

This is a continuation of a question I posted last week that I'm still having trouble with. I'm trying to write a Rational class containing two private instance variables num and den whose datatype is BigInteger. The Rational constructor takes two int's as their parameters.
My problem is whenever I write the add or multiply method in my Rational class Eclipse gives me an error. I don't know why it give me an error. As I understand it, the operators +, -, *, / can only be used on primitive datatypes and since my private instance variables are BigInteger's they are nonpprimitive datatypes and any addition or multiplication will have to be done through the add or multiply method.
The code below gives me an error but I don't know why. I don't understand what's conceptually wrong with the code. Is the reason for the error something conceptual with using this.num/this.den/r.num/r.den in the methods or does the error have to do with something related to syntax? The error for the add and multiply methods are the same and it says "The constructor Rational(BigInteger,BigInteger) is undefined".

```
public class Rational{


  public Rational(int x, int y) {
      num = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
      den = BigInteger.valueOf(y);
 }

  public Rational add(Rational r) {
     return new Rational(this.num.multiply(r.den).add(r.num.multiply(this.den)), this.den.multiply(r.den));
}

 public Rational multiply(Rational r) {
      return new Rational(this.num.multiply(r.num), this.den.multiply(r.den));
}


private BigInteger num;
private BigInteger den
}
```

Comment: Can you post the statck trace?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with that that is.

Comment: @codeMan: there won't be a stack trace, this is a compile-time issue, not a runtime issue.

Comment: @Mac Oh.. yeah! I see it now.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reinvent BigDecimal

Comment: @Bohemian Uh-oh I don't want to do that. =(

Comment: @Bohemian: Not really. BigDecimal has a fixed denominator of 10 (or powers thereof). It cannot really represent 1/3 or 1/7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor you have defined, takes 2 `int`s as arguments.

```
 public Rational(int x, int y) {
      num = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
      den = BigInteger.valueOf(y);
 }
```

and the compiler complains because you are passing two `BigIntegers`.

Have a new overloaded Constructor

```
 public Rational(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {
      num = x;
      den = y;
 }
```

Comment: Where "Overloaded" means that you add this new constructor in addition to the existing one (which you can keep).

Comment: so the best solution is to create another different constructor?

Comment: Ok I totally get my mistake and I can't believe I missed it. In the add or multiply method, it returns a new Rational but with datatype BigInteger. You can't use the same Rational constructor because that constructor only accepts int's for it's parameters. So, to solve that problem you need another constructor that accepts two BigInteger's as it's parameters therefore resulting in the answer above.